# Matrix not being formed and getting parsing error using fromJson

Tags: github, github-actions

I have created a workflow that uses boolean input values as a condition to create dynamic matrix that will be used to deploy to different sites based on the boolean values above.

.yml file

```
name: Deploy-Dev/Staging-All_Brands

on:
  inputs:
      env:
        type: choice
        description: Which environment do you want to deploy to?
        options:
          - development
          - staging
      coachRetail:
        type: boolean
        description: Coach Retal US/Canada
      coachRetailAB:
        type: boolean
        description: Coach Retail AB Testing
      coachOutlet:
        type: boolean
        description: Coach Outlet US/Canada
      ksUs:
        type: boolean
        description: Katespade US/Katespade Surprise
      allJapan:
        type: boolean
        description: Coach, Coach Outlet and Katespade Japan
      sw:
        type: boolean
        description: StuartWeitzman US/CA
      coachEu:
        type: boolean
        description: Coach UK, Germany, France, Italy and Spain
      ksEu:
        type: boolean
        description: Katespade UK, Germany and Europe
jobs:
  prep_matrix:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      matrix: ${{steps.set-matrix.outputs.matrix}}
    steps:
      - id: set-matrix
        run: |
          branchName=$(echo ${GITHUB_REF#refs/heads/} | sed 's/\//_/g')
          coachRetail=${{github.event.inputs.coachRetail}}
          coachOutlet=${{github.event.inputs.coachOutlet}}
          ksUs=${{github.event.inputs.ksUs}}
          sw=${{github.event.inputs.sw}}
          coachEu=${{github.event.inputs.coachEu}}
          allJapan=${{github.event.inputs.allJapan}}
          ksEu=${{github.event.inputs.ksEu}}
          coachRetailAB=${{github.event.inputs.coachRetailAB}}
          matrix=$(jq --arg 'map(
            . | select((($coachRetail == "true") and (.deploy_id == "coachRetail")) or (($coachOutlet == "true") and (.deploy_id == "coachOutlet")) or (($ksUs == "true") and (.deploy_id == "ksUs")) or (($sw == "true") and (.deploy_id == "sw")) or (($coachEu == "true") and (.deploy_id == "coachEu")) or (($allJapan == "true") and (.deploy_id == "allJapan")) or (($ksEu == "true") and (.deploy_id == "ksEu")) or (($coachRetailAB == "true") and (.deploy_id == "coachRetailAB")))
          )' deployment_matrix.json )
          echo "matrix={\"include\":$(echo $matrix)}" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT

  deploy-to-xdn:
    if: contains(github.ref, 'refs/tags') == false || github.event_name == 'release'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: prep_matrix
    strategy:
      fail-fast: false
      matrix: ${{fromJson(needs.prep_matrix.outputs.matrix)}}
    steps:
      - name: Test Output
        run: |
         echo ${{matrix}}
```

.json file

```
[
  {
    "project": "Coach",
    "deploy_id": "coachRetail"
  },
  {
    "project": "Coach AB",
    "deploy_id": "coachRetailAB"
  },
  {
    "project": "Coach-Outlet",
    "deploy_id": "coachOutlet"
  },
  {
    "project": "Katespade",
    "deploy_id": "ksUs"
  },
  {
    "project": "Katespade Surprise",
    "deploy_id": "ksUs"
  },
  {
    "project": "Coach (Japan)",
    "deploy_id": "allJapan"
  },
  {
    "project": "Coach Outlet (Japan)",
    "deploy_id": "allJapan"
  },
  {
    "project": "Katespade (Japan)",
    "deploy_id": "allJapan"
  },
  {
    "project": "Coach Canada",
    "deploy_id": "coachRetail"
  },
  {
    "project": "Coach-Outlet Canada",
    "deploy_id": "coachOutlet"
  },
  {
    "project": "StuartWeitzman",
    "deploy_id": "sw"
  },
  {
    "project": "StuartWeitzman Canada",
    "deploy_id": "sw"
  },
  {
    "project": "Coach UK",
    "deploy_id": "coachEu"
  },
  {
    "project": "Coach DE",
    "deploy_id": "coachEu"
  },
  {
    "project": "Coach FR",
    "deploy_id": "coachEu"
  },
  {
    "project": "Coach IT",
    "deploy_id": "coachEu"
  },
  {
    "project": "Coach Spain",
    "deploy_id": "coachEu"
  },
  {
    "project": "Katespade UK",
    "deploy_id": "ksEu"
  },
  {
    "project": "Katespade DE",
    "deploy_id": "ksEu"
  },
  {
    "project": "Katespade EU",
    "deploy_id": "ksEu"
  }
]
```

Now when I run the workflow, I want that the inputs which are ticked should form the matrix using the json file above.

But when I tried testing it on the branch using hardcoded values for coachRetail, coachOutlut, ksUs like:

`coachRetail="true"`

it gives the following error:

```
Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: }
Unexpected value ''
```

I guess the matrix is not being formed here.

How can I rectify this and debug further?

Comment: Workflow trigger is missing after `on`. Most probably, it would be `workflow_dispatch`. To print `matrix`, use `echo '${{ toJSON(matrix) }}'` or `jq . <<< '${{ toJSON(matrix) }}'`.

Comment: Also, I noticed that while populating `matrix` before setting the output, quotes are not being escaped to make it a string literal to be used by `fromJSON` later. That might be an issue. With `jq`, you may need `@json` at the end to escape those.

Comment: ```
steps:
      - id: set-matrix
        run: |
          branchName=$(echo ${GITHUB_REF#refs/heads/} | sed 's/\//_/g')
          coachRetail=\"true\"
          matrix=$(jq --arg 'map(
            . | select((($coachRetail == "true") and (.deploy_id == "coachRetail"))
          )' deployment_matrix.json )
          echo "matrix={\"include\":$(echo $matrix)}" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT

  output_matrix:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: prep_matrix
    steps:
      - name: Output Matrix
        run: echo `${{ needs.prep_matrix.outputs.matrix  }}`
```

Still empty matrix
@az

Comment: @Azeem What do you mean by quotes not being escaped? Where exactly?

Comment: Print `matrix` right after populating it before setting it as output parameter. Have you verified it?

Comment: Giving me null, the matrix

Comment: Then, you should first verify your `jq` filters. The actual issue may be there.

Comment: @Azeem Where should we place this json file?

Comment: JSON file? Aren't you assigning it directly to `matrix` variable?

Comment: I am trying to read the JSON file mentioned as deployment_matrix.json in the jq filter query. But it seems to not find it.

Comment: You don't have a checkout step in your workflow. You need to add it. See https://github.com/actions/checkout.

Comment: How to do so? I have the json file in the same folder as the .yml file.

Comment: Under `.github/workflows` directory?

Comment: Yes correct, its under that directory

Comment: You'll have to add a checkout step before using that file. Use its correct path i.e. `.github/workflows/deployment_matrix.json` with `jq`.

Comment: I have added this step:
- name: Checkout Repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          token: ${{secrets.TOKEN}}

Comment: `- uses: actions/checkout@v3` should be enough.